# Data value has invalid format error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run a query that includes only the past 90 days worth of data, but the query is returning the error "Data value...has invalid format".

The query is:

```
select name, diff
from
    (select name, (getdate()::date - to_date(split_part(name, ' ', 1),'MM/DD/YYYY')::date) as diff
    from sample_table)
where diff<=90;
```

The strange part is that the operation `getdate()::date - to_date(split_part(name, ' ', 1),'MM/DD/YYYY')::date` works as expected, but when restricted to <=90, it returns this error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This simply means that there are some values in that `name` column that cannot be converted to a `date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The query runs successfully if the `where diff<=90` clause is removed, so I'm sure that the conversion to data has no issues.

Comment: Did you see the proposed answer below on finding your poorly formatted row?

Answer (score 0):

Find the bad row using the following code:

```
select split_part(name,' ',1) original_value, name
from sample_table
where split_part(name,'1') !~ '^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
```

This uses regex to determine if there's a valid date in that part of the field-- if not, it returns the field so you may find it.

Comment: the issue is not caused by the split_part() function. As I mentioned in the question, the strange part is that the operation `getdate()::date - to_date(split_part(name, ' ', 1),'MM/DD/YYYY')::date` works as expected, but when restricted to <=90, it returns the error.

Comment: I believe it is. See, postgres optimizes a host of things. Did you happen to run my query to see if any results are returned? If nothing's returned, I'll do further research.